# Viewing the calls stack for a particular method

Tags: java, callstack

Is it possible to view the complete list of call stack for a given method in my application using any tool?

I want to see the similar result that I can see in JProfiler for a given method.

However I am looking for some open source/free alternative and without having to do too much of configuration setup.

Comment: Could you just edit the method and have it print a stack trace as soon as it's invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but maybe you are looking something like this method

```
class MyInfo{
    static void showStack(){
        try{
            throw new Exception();
        }catch(Exception e){
            StackTraceElement[] ste=e.getStackTrace();
            for(int i=1; i<ste.length;i++){
                System.out.println(ste[i].getClassName()+"."+ste[i].getMethodName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Lets try it

```
class C1 {
    void methodA() {MyInfo.showStack();}
    void methodB() {methodA();}
}

class C2 {
    static void methodX() {
        C1 c1 = new C1();
        c1.methodB();
    };
    //TEST
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C2.methodX();
    }
}
```

out

```
C1.methodA
C1.methodB
C2.methodX
C2.main
```

Answer (score 1):

JConsole, which comes with the jdk has a Threads tab, that lists all the running threads. When you select one, it will show the trace. You can connect to a local process without any setup. If you're remote, you have to enable the remote connector as a start up option. Screen shot is from jdk 1.7.  [image: JConsole]

Answer (score 0):

Would this get you what you want?

[`java.lang.Throwable.getStackTrace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace)